# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).jqzoom is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am using multiple jquery on same page... I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).jqzoom is not a function
```

My code is:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.jqzoom').jqzoom({
    zoomType: 'standard',
    lens:true,
    preloadImages: false,
    alwaysOn:false,
    zoomWidth: 200,
    zoomHeight: 200,
    xOffset:90,
    yOffset:30,
    position:'left'
   });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: make sure the script which has `jqzoom` plugin is loaded

Comment: I see an error in the full page code. "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" : twice script tag one in the other....it's better for me if you make a jsbin test page and share it here.

Comment: and double check the jQuery plugin is in top of other included JS..

Comment: Why is this question tagged as `php`?

Comment: Thank you guys..... jqzoom plugin is loaded.. and its top on all other JS... I am not getting any kind of SyntaxError

Comment: Still not able to get expected output...........

Comment: can you share the link to the page?